# Seeking an Advanced Content-Based Photo Organization Android App

Tags: gallery, android-app

I am searching for a Android application capable of intelligently organizing a large collection of photos and graphics, such as screenshots and downloaded images. Key features I'm looking for include:

Content Analysis: Ability to analyze and categorize images based on their content, beyond standard EXIF data. For instance, automatically identifying and sorting screenshots from a language learning app into a "Language Learning" folder, historical event images into a "History" folder, and news article screenshots into a "News" folder.

Automatic Folder Creation: The app should automatically create and name folders based on the identified content categories.

Learning Capability: Preferably, the app should learn and adapt to my organizational preferences over time, potentially with an initial learning phase where I guide the categorization process.

Background Operation: The sorting and organizing should occur in the background, with minimal need for manual intervention after initial setup.

Cross-Device Compatibility: Ideally, the app's organizational structure should be maintained when transferring the sorted photos to other devices, even without the app installed on them.

I am seeking recommendations for such an app or any information about existing apps that closely match these specifications. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is basically a knowledge management system with recognition (such as OCR) and machine-learning capabilities for automated tagging. I doubt that you'll find any freeware solution, only government agencies use them. For ordinary users only manual tagging tools are currently available, which you can google on the Internet. There is a number of on-going open projects aiming at facilitating future AI technologies, including WordNet and ImageNet. But none of them has resulted yet into something that would match your description, at least as far as I am aware.